# ActiveAdmin Autocomplete

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have a model called **LetterResponse**

**belongs_to :user**

LetterResponse have following field (just shortening my model)

```
:id
:title
:user_id
```

while admin creates new letter_response he will fill the title and when he types user name it should autofill

I have 100k users so can't do

```
f.input :response_user_id, :as => :select, :collection => 
  User.all.collect {|user| [user.first_name, user.user_id] }, label: "Parent"
```

even choozen-rails gem does same pre loads data.

so tried with activeadmin-addons ajax-search by following

https://github.com/platanus/activeadmin_addons/blob/master/docs/select2_search.md

```
f.input :response_user_id, as: :search_select, url: admin_users_path,
          fields: [:user_last_name], display_name: 'name', 
                minimum_input_length: 2
```

but I get an error:

> undefined method response_user

How to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't your input field be :user_id instead of :response_user_id, (becuase you mention your LetterResponse has a belongs_to :user relation (not belongs_to :response_user.

So, it should look like

```
f.input :user_id, as: :search_select, url: admin_users_path, fields: [:user_last_name], display_name: 'name', minimum_input_length: 2
```